# tkinter puts WAY too much space between checkbuttons

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I can't figure out how to get tkinter to put checkbuttons and radiobuttons closer together.  Even specifying pady=0 anyplace it seems valid has no effect.  The vertical distance between the buttons is unnaturally large, ugly, and just wastes space.  In order to make a set of buttons appear as a group separate from other controls requires that I add extra space elsewhere, which just gets out of control.

Here's a working example I extracted:

```
from Tkinter import *

def rbtest(frame):
    group = LabelFrame( frame, text="Target", padx=0, pady=0)

    btnVal = StringVar(frame,' ')
    for b in ( "option1", "another option", "Someth Else", "go away"):
        rb=Radiobutton( group, text=b, value=b, variable=btnVal)
        rb.pack( anchor=W, pady=2)

    boardname = StringVar()
    Label( group, text="Name").pack( anchor=W)
    Entry( group, text=boardname).pack()

    group.pack( side=LEFT, fill=Y, padx=0, pady=0)

tk = Tk()
rbtest(tk)
tk.mainloop()
```

[Well, I can't post an image showing what it produces because I don't have enough reputation, so sorry about that... I tried.]

**Edit:** I'm using Python 2.6.6 and Windows 7.

Considering how closely together it packs other elements, I'm surprised this is normal behavior, but all the examples I've found on the web look similar...

Comment: Note: The code I posted was stale... showed pady=2 on pack, and had no pady=0 in the constructor.  Yes, setting pady=0 on both calls does help, but there's still too much space.  (I've left the code unchanged so as not to create a moving target.)

Comment: Could you link us a picture of you're window when you run it? That may help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran your code on a Mac and on a windows box, and in both cases it looked about right to me. If you want them literally as close as possible, set the `borderwidth` to zero and the `pady` option to zero.

To eek out another two pixels between each button, set the `highlightthickness` to zero, though that  affects the user experience when they are using keyboard traversal.

Comment: Could you maybe post a graphic showing what yours looks like in Windows when you run the example?  That would really help me confirm whether I'm seeing the same thing you are.

Comment: I had accidentally left pady=2 from my misguided attempts to fix it (oops), which accounted for most of the spaciness in the code I posted.  pady=0 still seemed like too much space, but borderwidth=0 did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It looks pretty normal to me:

[image: screenshot of window]

If it really needs to be made super-compact, there are ways of doing so, but I suspect your system is rendering the window differently.

Comment: I really appreciate the visual. Yours rendered very similar to mine.